# SBT plugin dependency resolution fails with com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.1: not found

Tags: playframework, sbt

I've a Play app and when I ran `sbt`, I got an error as follows:

```
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin/2.2.1/sbt-plugin-2.2.1.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.2.1 (sbtVersion=0.13, scalaVersion=2.10)
```

But actually, the path of this plugin is `http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com.typesafe.play/` rather than the failed trial `http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play`.

**project/plugin.sbt** looks as follows:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
```

Please advise.

Comment: Why do you use `sbt` not `play`? Where is the file with `resolvers` and `addSbtPlugin`? In `project` directory?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, I wanted to use sbt, and there is no reason for it not to work, right? Yes, it is inside `project` directory in the file plugin.sbt.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of sbt plugin seems to be `2.2.0` ([Migration guide says it](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Migration22)) so change your `plugins.sbt` like this:

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.0")
```

Comment: but still, my sbt does not seem to be searching the correct path somehow. Did you notice what I said ` the path of this plugin is http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com.typesafe.play/ rather than the failed trial http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/play`?

Answer (score 1):

The play plugin is distributed as an ivy artifact, not a maven one.  You need the following:

```
resolvers += Resolver.typesafeIvyRepo("releases")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
```

See the contents here: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/

Please note that the latest version of Play (and hence the plugin) is **2.2.2**.

Comment: still, it was trying with `[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/2.2.1/ivys/ivy.xml` which isn't the link you put up here `http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.2.1/`

Comment: It's been changed to reflect where exactly SBT searches for the plugin.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Note: the /releases/ directory is a "mirror" of /ivy-releases/

Comment: Wow, but you can download the contents directly?  sounds like some kind of bug.

Comment: @jsuereth I am behind a proxy and facing a similar issue with version 2.6.5. Can you elaborate a little bit on "Note: the /releases/ directory is a "mirror" of /ivy-releases/ ", what exactly did you mean?