# UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES — com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.3: not found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I am trying to build a Play/Scala project in Intellij. But some dependencies are not found.

**What am I doing wrong?**

I have set Intellij to use Scala 2.11.8, but the output might mean that a different version is used (?).

I have tried ideas from a previous similar question, but it did not help:

[SBT plugin dependency resolution fails with com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.1: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234447/sbt-plugin-dependency-resolution-fails-with-com-typesafe-playsbt-plugin2-2-1)

**plugins.sbt**

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// Resolvers
resolvers += "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository mvn" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"

// Sbt plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.vmunier" % "sbt-play-scalajs" % "0.2.6")

addSbtPlugin("org.scala-js" % "sbt-scalajs" % "0.6.3")
```

**build.properties**

```
sbt.version=1.1.2
```

**build.sbt**

```
lazy val scalaV = "2.11.8"

lazy val `my_project` = (project in file(".")).settings(
  scalaVersion := scalaV,
  scalaJSProjects := Seq(client),
  pipelineStages := Seq(scalaJSProd),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "com.vmunier" %% "play-scalajs-scripts" % "0.2.2",
    "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.4.0",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "angular-chart.js" % "0.7.1",
    "org.webjars.bower" % "angular-growl-2" % "0.7.4",
    jdbc,
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
    "org.jooq" % "jooq" % "3.7.0",
    "org.jooq" % "jooq-codegen-maven" % "3.7.0",
    "org.jooq" % "jooq-meta" % "3.7.0"
  ),
  WebKeys.importDirectly := true
).enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(client).aggregate(client)
```

**Output**

```
Error while importing sbt project:

[info] Loading settings from idea.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/me/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from /home/me/projects/myproject
[warn]  module not found: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.3
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.4.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.4.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/me/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.4.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/sbt-plugin_2.12_1.0/2.4.3/sbt-plugin-2.4.3.pom
...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.4.3: not found
[warn]  :: com.vmunier#sbt-play-scalajs;0.2.6: not found
[warn]  :: org.scala-js#sbt-scalajs;0.6.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
...
```

**Update: Output after I changed SBT version to 0.13.10**

```
Error while importing sbt project:

error: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', required by /home/me/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.6/lib/scala-library.jar(scala/package.class)
error: error while loading package, Missing dependency 'object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror', required by /home/me/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.6/lib/scala-library.jar(scala/runtime/package.class)
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:16)
at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:48)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:40)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:61)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:99)
at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:102)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:264)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.ObjectClass(Definitions.scala:264)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnyRefClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:263)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnyRefClass(Definitions.scala:263)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.specialPolyClass(Definitions.scala:1120)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RepeatedParamClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:407)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.RepeatedParamClass(Definitions.scala:407)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1154)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreClasses(Definitions.scala:1152)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1196)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1196)
at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1261)
at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1290)
at sbt.compiler.Eval$$anon$1.<init>(Eval.scala:141)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.run$lzycompute$1(Eval.scala:141)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.run$1(Eval.scala:141)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.unlinkAll$1(Eval.scala:144)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.evalCommon(Eval.scala:153)
at sbt.compiler.Eval.eval(Eval.scala:96)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateDslEntry(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:177)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$9.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:117)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$$anonfun$9.apply(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at sbt.EvaluateConfigurations$.evaluateSbtFile(EvaluateConfigurations.scala:115)
at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$loadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:725)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:731)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1$1.apply(Load.scala:730)
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.getOrElse(MapLike.scala:128)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.getOrElse(Map.scala:58)
at sbt.Load$.sbt$Load$$memoLoadSettingsFile$1(Load.scala:730)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:738)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$loadFiles$1$2.apply(Load.scala:738)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at sbt.Load$.loadFiles$1(Load.scala:738)
at sbt.Load$.discoverProjects(Load.scala:749)
at sbt.Load$.discover$1(Load.scala:555)
at sbt.Load$.loadTransitive(Load.scala:584)
at sbt.Load$.loadProjects$1(Load.scala:452)
at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:456)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:291)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:291)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:344)
at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:299)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:295)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:286)
at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:140)
at sbt.Load$.buildPluginDefinition(Load.scala:836)
at sbt.Load$.buildPlugins(Load.scala:802)
at sbt.Load$.plugins(Load.scala:790)
at sbt.Load$.loadUnit(Load.scala:441)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:291)
at sbt.Load$$anonfun$18$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Load.scala:291)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:91)
at sbt.BuildLoader$$anonfun$componentLoader$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BuildLoader.scala:90)
at sbt.BuildLoader.apply(BuildLoader.scala:140)
at sbt.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:344)
at sbt.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:299)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:295)
at sbt.Load$.load(Load.scala:286)
at sbt.Load$.apply(Load.scala:140)
at sbt.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:36)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:492)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:492)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:484)
at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2.apply(Main.scala:484)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Command.scala:59)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
at sbt.Command$$anonfun$applyEffect$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(Command.scala:61)
at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:93)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:184)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:96)
at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:89)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:68)
at sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:63)
at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:63)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:46)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:30)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:22)
at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:54)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Invalid response.
```

**Update: Output after I changed SBT version to 0.13.18**

```
...
[error] (client/*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-js#scalajs-compiler_2.11.8;0.6.3: not found
[error] (myproject/*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-js#scalajs-compiler_2.11.8;0.6.3: not found
[error] (client/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scala-js#scalajs-compiler_2.11.8;0.6.3: not found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Play Sbt plugin `2.4.3` is not compatible with `Sbt 1.x` release, but only with `0.13.x`

If you need to keep Play framework at version `2.4.3`, you should downgrade Sbt to `0.13.18`

**build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.18
```

Otherwise you should pick a more recent Play framework version

Comment: I think I will have to start with Play Sbt plugin 2.4.3, because it's a sample project that I just want to deploy first, and if I got it right, upgrading Play will probably require upgrading the code. I changed the version as you had suggested... now I am getting the error that I posted above. Any idea why it is? P.S. did you mean change sbt.version to 0.13.10 or 0.13.18?

Comment: Regarding the following error `java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found` have you tried to clean the project (`sbt clean`) ?

Comment: Sorry I fixed the comment, Sbt 0.13.18 is the greatest sbt 0.13.x release

Comment: When I run the sbt task "clean", I get the same long error output. I also tried "invalidate caches & restart" option, but still getting this error output after intellij restarted.

Comment: Ok, please try to manually delete the `project/target` directory, and the start sbt from command line. Only after that, start IntelliJ and reload the sbt project from there

Comment: I made a mistake, I had to run instead the build with sbt.version=0.13.18, then I get a different error message (see update above). So some dependencies do not exist. It seems like it's because of the specific Scala version that I set up (2.11.8). How can I know what Scala version would work with this project?

Comment: The greatest scala version for `scalajs-compiler v0.6.3` is `scala 2.11.6` ref. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-js/scalajs-compiler

Regarding your last question, all of this should have been explicitly set and versioned in your project, both sbt and scala version

Comment: I looked again at the project that I downloaded, and it did not have the file `project/build.properties` with `sbt.version`, so it was probably created when I imported the project to Intellij, but with a wrong sbt.version. Is this file an official part of the SBT program, or is it specific for Intellij? Is there an easy way for me to know what the correct sbt.version for a project is? Isn't SBT supposed to be backward compatible?

Comment: yes, `project/build.properties` is always part of a sbt project and it's not IntelliJ specific.
There is no easy way to retrieve the version if they have been lost.
The issue is that you are crossing a major SBT refactoring moving from the 0.13.x  version to the 1.x version. The 1.x have many improvements but is not backward compatible

Comment: Thank you, this answers my questions. I was able now to get the project to compile. The projects I am trying to use are from a code sample repository for a book. The code is not maintained anymore. I will try to upgrade the dependencies and environment, but the first step was to get the original code to compile, since I know that it is supposed to work.